# Adding individual pieces of data to multiple listboxes?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am writing code for a program that requires the user to input data about their home.  They have two choices.  They can enter info about their home or apartment.  They enter data about the property id, address, bedrooms, year built, price, and square footage and they in two separate textboxes they enter information of whether its furnished(this is for the apartment option) or they enter the garage capacity(this is for the house option).  The six parameters apply to the base class and the furnished or garage capacity are the two subclasses for either apartment or house.  when the user clicks the "add apartment" or "add house" button the address should either go into the apartment listbox or the home listbox.  This is where i am hitting a snag.

```
private void btnAddApartment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //instantiate appartment and add it to arraylist
    try
    {
        Apartment anApartment = new Apartment(txtID.Text, txtAddress.Text, int.Parse(txtYearBuilt.Text), int.Parse(txtBedrooms.Text),
            double.Parse(txtSquareFootage.Text), double.Parse(txtPrice.Text), txtFurnished.Text);
        Home.Add(anApartment);
        ClearText(this);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Make sure you entered everything correctly!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }            

}

private void btnAddHouse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try 
    {
        House aHouse=new House(txtID.Text, txtAddress.Text, int.Parse(txtYearBuilt.Text), int.Parse(txtBedrooms.Text),
            double.Parse(txtSquareFootage.Text), double.Parse(txtPrice.Text),int.Parse(txtGarageCapacity.Text));
        Home.Add(aHouse);
        AddHouseToListBox();
        ClearText(this);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Make sure you entered everything correctly!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }
}

private void ClearText(Control controls)
{
    foreach (Control control in controls.Controls)
    {
        if (control is TextBox)
        {
            ((TextBox)control).Clear();
        }
    }
}

private void AddHouseToListBox()
{
    lstHouse.Items.Clear();
    foreach (House person in Home)
    {
        lstHouse.Items.Add(person.GetAddress());
    }
}


private void AddApartmentToListBox()
{
    lstApartment.Items.Clear();
    foreach (Apartment persons in Home)
    {
        lstApartment.Items.Add(persons.GetAddress());
    }
}
```

Comment: asp.net? silverlight? wpf? winforms?

Comment: its in a C# windows form application

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `AddApartmentToListBox` in btnAddApartment_Click

```
private void btnAddApartment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//instantiate appartment and add it to arraylist
try
{
    Apartment anApartment = new Apartment(txtID.Text, txtAddress.Text, int.Parse(txtYearBuilt.Text), int.Parse(txtBedrooms.Text),
        double.Parse(txtSquareFootage.Text), double.Parse(txtPrice.Text), txtFurnished.Text);
    Home.Add(anApartment);
    AddApartmentToListBox();
    ClearText(this);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Make sure you entered everything correctly!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
}
```

}

Also instead of clearing and adding to the listbox every time you can replace `AddApartmentToListBox` with

```
lstApartment.Items.Add(anApartment.GetAddress());
```

and `AddHouseToListBox` with

```
lstHouse.Items.Add(aHouse.GetAddress());
```